# Is possible to chage DEBUG FLAG mode in runtime?

Tags: android

I'm thinking in change programmatically in run-time for a DEBUG to NO DEBUG versión of app.
I know the flag FLAG_DEBUGGABLE especificated by manifest.xml. Is posible change this value in run-time?. I think no because it would involve introduce/remove debug info in the app.

Thanks!.

Comment: When you want the same apk work in debug and real mode by a check into de app. Debug mode affect severals things: debug remote,  screen log, tokens debug for admob and code selection.

Comment: You could have some sharedprefs variable. Not as smooth though.